# Windows Store asset generator as command line tool

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-store-apps

UWP Application requires a lot of icons and logos in different sizes.

Do you know command line tool to generate assets from source image.

---

For example in Microsoft Terminal project: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal

- Source image: 
  [Terminal.svg](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/2af722b43d3213858df156cc42c47e12341b836a/res/terminal/Terminal.svg)
- Produced icons and logos: 
  [images](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/2af722b43d3213858df156cc42c47e12341b836a/res/terminal/images)

Comment: You could generate the images in Visual studio by the step: click .appxmanifest>Visual Assets>choose the source image> Generate.....

Answer (score 0):

You could use this open source solution which seems to generate all required assets (except badges):
https://github.com/tomzorz/UwpBetterTileGen